# Express js - How to get response from ajax call?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I am trying to send form data to server side using ajax (sending a username), and in the server side perform SQL query and pass back the result to my template (EJS).

In my server side (ajaxTest.js)

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
var query = connection.query("select * from account where username='" + req.body.username+ "'",function  (err,result) {
    console.log(query.sql);
    if (err)   {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.error(result);

    res.send("Result "+JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

});

In my template (ajaxTest.ejs)

```
$(document).ready(function  () {
$("#submit").on("submit",function  (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    data = {};
    data.username = 'user101'; 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/ajaxtest',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
})
```

});

In the above code, result is successfully logged onto my console, but the 'success' and data does not get returned. Is there a reason why result is not being sent back to the template (ajaxTest.ejs)?

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback on the situation!

Comment: Why not use `res.json(JSON.stringify(result))`?

Comment: @Aer0 i tried res.json as well, it won't work too. is this the right way of getting back success data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res.send("Result "+JSON.stringify(result));
```

sends not valid json.

Either use:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
```

or

```
res.json(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are corrupting the syntax of JSON by prepending it with 'Result'.

```
 res.send("Result "+JSON.stringify(result));
```

Instead do simple

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your front-end expects json data. Your back end should returned corresponding data too.

on your node.js, please change the return line from

```
res.send("Result "+JSON.stringify(result));
```

to

```
res.status(201).json(result); // return status 201, and json data (do not stringify)
```